# Can the set in which a sequence is unbonded be $\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, continuity, rational-numbers, baire-category

Let be $f_n:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow[0, +\infty)$ as sequence of continuous and non-negative functions. Can $\{f_n\}_{n\geq1}$ exist such that:
$$\{\ x \in \mathbb{R}\ |\ \sup_{n\geq1}f_n(x)=+\infty\}=\mathbb{Q}?$$
How can I prove that this statement is either false or true by using the Baire's category theorem and knowing that $\mathbb{Q}$ is a $F_\sigma$ set?

I wanted to prove that the set  $\{\ x \in \mathbb{R}\ |\ \sup_{n\geq1}f_n(x)=+\infty\}$ is a $G_\delta$ but I don't know how.

Comment: That is $\cap_k \cup_n \{  x \mid f_n(x) > k\}$, isn't it?

Comment: Wait, I actually wrote it in the wrong way when I tried to proove it, I first wrote the countable union on $n$ and then on $k$. This should proove because I have the countable intersection of open sets that is a $G_\delta$. Thank you so much, I'm feeling very dumb.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We have
$$
\sup_{n\geq1}f_n(x)=+\infty \iff \forall k \in \Bbb N: \sup_{n\geq1}f_n(x) > k\\
\iff \forall k \in \Bbb N: \exists n \in \Bbb N: f_n(x) > k
$$
and therefore
$$
\{\ x \in \mathbb{R} \mid \sup_{n\geq1}f_n(x)=+\infty\} = \bigcap_{k\ge 1} \bigcup_{n\ge 1} \{  x \in \Bbb R \mid f_n(x) > k\}
$$
and that is a $G_\delta$ set.